# Only allow pagebreak between lefthand and righthand page in double sided document

Tags: page-breaking, enumerate, minipage, double-sided

I'm working on a songbook, using the class scrbook.
Every song is a single file imported using `\input`.  I'm using `\enumerate` for the verses and refrain.
At the moment, I put the whole song in a minipage, to prevent pagebreaks in between the song, so the single files look like this:

```
\begin{minipage}
\section*{Title of the song}
\begin{enumerate}

\item first line of first verse\\
      second line of first verse\\
      third line of first verse\\
      and so on

\item [] first line of first refrain\\
and so on

\item etc...

\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
```

That prevents any pagebreaks (If a song is too long for one page, i have to insert a \newpage manually).

What I want to do ist allow pagebreaks between the verses from a left hand to a right hand page, but not from a right hand to a  left hand page.

Is there some command or package which can do this?

Comment: Just put a \parbox{\linewidth}{first line\\...} in each \item.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not quite satisfied myself with this “hacky” solution, you could achive such behavior by conditionally changing the page break penalties of lists: If the song starts on an odd page, page breaks between `enumerate` environments would be disallowed, but allowed on even pages.

However, this requires that (a) no song (on an odd page) would be larger than a single page, and that (b) a song consists of only a single `enumerate` environment.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\songpenalties}{%
    \checkoddpage%
    \ifoddpage%
        \@itempenalty 10000% disallows page breaks between items in a list
        \widowpenalties 1 10000% disallows page breaks between lines inside a verse
    \else%
        \@itempenalty 0% allows page breaks between items in a list
        \widowpenalties 1 10000% disallows page breaks between lines inside a verse
        % \widowpenalties 0% if you would like to have page breaks between lines 
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\demosong}
{%
    \section*{Title of the song}
    \begin{enumerate}

        \item first line of first verse\\
            second line of first verse\\
            third line of first verse\\
            and so on

        \item [] first line of first refrain\\
            and so on

        \item first line of second verse\\
            second line of second verse\\
            third line of second verse\\
            and so on

        \item [] first line of first refrain\\
            and so on

        \item etc...

    \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}

    \raggedbottom

    \songpenalties % prepend each song with the \songpenalties
    \demosong % replace these with your \input-s (without minipages)

    \songpenalties
    \demosong

    \songpenalties
    \demosong

    \songpenalties
    \demosong

    \songpenalties
    \demosong

\end{document}
```

The compiled document would look like this:
[image: img]

Comment: I think you mean `\interlinepenalty`, not `\widowpenalties 1`.  *Very* hacky solution, though!

Comment: Forgot to add: you should add to your list of caveat the condition that each `\item` mustn’t contain more than one paragraph (and no sublists, no displayed equations… ;-)